# ¿Es posible compartir una imagen con texto adjunto vía WhatsApp en iOS con Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart

Actualmente necesito compartir un voucher por medio de WhatsApp, estoy utilizando la librería:

> share_files_and_screenshot_widgets v1.0.6

con la cual se realiza una captura de pantalla a un widget específico, que es la imagen que se busca compartir, incluyendo una breve descripción adjunta a la imagen.

Este comportamiento se realiza correctamente para Android, pero en iOS se puede enviar solo texto o solo imagen.

Este es el código que tengo actualmente:

```
  final RenderRepaintBoundary? boundary = globalKey.currentContext!
      .findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary?;
  if (kDebugMode) {
    if (boundary!.debugNeedsPaint) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10));
      return share();
    }
  }

  ShareFilesAndScreenshotWidgets().shareScreenshot(
    globalKey,
    1200,
    "Titulo",
    "screenshot.png",
    "image/png",
    text: "Texto adjunto",
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Por políticas de seguridad, bastantes App's EN IOS, restringen muchísimos datos, no es que no te los muestre, o que este haciendo algo mal tu código, las políticas de Whats App en ios , tienen una restricción muy alta en el envió y cifrado de datos.

La otra que úede intentar , es maquetar el envio de datos con Future, en vez de ese plugin